# Lock screen without turning off

Tags: android, lockscreen

Using the [lockNow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29) function the display is turned off and then locked, but how to lock the display keeping it on?
I'd like to know if exists a way to invoke the lock screen without turning the display off so the user can (eventually) unlock it without the necessity to press down the power button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to turn the screen on after the [lockNow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29) call with something like that:

```
PowerManager powerManager = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
WakeLock screenLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
screenLock.acquire();
screenLock.release();
```

You will need to add the required permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Ok Addrallyn i've achieved the same conclusion but by recurring to an activity (FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) that immediately finishes. Your, even if a workaround in turn, is more elegant than mine. I'll accept your answer unless there is a solution that does not involve an ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast receiver.

Comment: it seems that there isn't a function that locks the screen without turning it off first.

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way to lock screen. Try that one. It may work differently and not turn of the screen (I can't say exactly, you can check it). Instead of using `lockNow()`, you can try to utilize [KeyguardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html). You can manipulate your `lockscreen` by changing `keyguard` properties.

Add required permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Then you can try something like this:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock l = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
l.reenableKeyguard();
```

Comment: unfortunately reenableKeyguard() seems to have no effect, at least on my development devices. Device's display is not turned off but it remains unlocked.